# Is there a way to dynamically load claims in OpenIddict?

Tags: openiddict

We have an application where there are lots of permissions as claims. Loading these when the user user logs in and setting them as part of the token makes the token very large.

My thinking was to find some way of load and adding claims dynamically to the token on every call (maybe from cache to speed it up).

I know openiddict offers a bunch of server events and am wondering if one of these might be a good place to put this logic.

Is there another way this can be achieved?

Our API is designed using many permissions and I don't wish to load them each time and put code inside each api to achieve this so adding claims to the principal seems logical.

Would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> Our API is designed using many permissions and I don't wish to load them each time and put code inside each api to achieve this so adding claims to the principal seems logical.

Then what you currently have is pretty much your best option. You could also enable reference access tokens to store the actual token payloads in the DB and make the tokens returned to the clients smaller.

If you were willing to do that at the API level, you could use the claims transformation mechanism to add claims on-the-fly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Great I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks to Kevin, I found my answer. Here's an example of what I did:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71875250/how-to-automatically-retrieve-roles-from-asp-net-core-identity/